# Usage of 'just so'

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, books

There was this dialog in Don Delillo's Cosmopolis which puzzled me:

(A little context, the main character Eric talks to his female bodyguard Kendra, who he had sex with just before, Torval is Eric's chief of security.)

> "What's he going to say to you about this?"
>
> "Torval?  Is that who you're talking about?'  She was amused.  "Say
>   his name."
>
> "What's he going to say to you?"
>
> "Just so you're safe.  That's his job," she said.

I can't interpret the term 'just so' in this context, I was thinking that maybe she's continuing some speech she began earlier on, but that's surely not the case.

I'd understand the sentence 'just so you're safe' in the sense of

'Why did you do this to me?' - 'Just so you're safe.'

but I can't figure it out here.

Comment: *Just so you're safe* is ambiguous. It could be reporting either Kendra's priority, regardless of what Torval thinks; or she could be reporting what Torval will actually think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just "shorthand" for "He (Torval) doesn't (or maybe has no right to) care what I do (what we do) just so long as we keep you safe. That's his only job: just to keep you safe."

Comment: I think this would answer the question better if you pointed out that Torval ***just*** (only) cares about keeping Eric safe.